# Simple Custom CSS on Wordpress not functioning

Tags: css, wordpress

This is the custom CSS I'm trying to add:

```
.resp-vtabs resp-tabs-container {
background-color : #000000;
border-left : 1px solid #000000 !important ;
clear : none;
float : left;
margin-left : -1px;
min-height : 244px;
padding : 0;
width : 68%;
}
```

This is the site I'm trying to add it to:
[Swish-Swank](http://swish-swank.com/product/black-duffle-bag/#woocomerce-tabs1)

I'm looking to make the white description, additional information and reviews black

Answer (score 3, accepted):

resp-tabs-container is unidentified it should be `.resp-tabs-container` for your css rules to work on your site